# In Django, how to check if user is in site_id (site_id are created by after)

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys

the objective of the system is to check if the user is in such site_id or not to display a part of the html page to him

**here I do it with groups :**

views.py

```
def is_admin(user):
    return user.groups.filter(id=1).exists()

def is_client(user):
    return user.groups.filter(id=4).exists()
```

template (main_list.html)

```
{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
    {% if 1 == group.id %}
```

and I would like to do it with my site_id (Foreign Key)

**here is my first attempt :**

views.py

```
def is_siteone(user):
    return user.site_id.filter(id=1).exists()
```

template (main_list.html)

```
{% if is_siteone %}
```

models.py

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    version = models.CharField(verbose_name='Program version', blank=False, default='1.0', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def filter(self, id):
        pass
```

but it returns the following error
[error return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ8Cr.jpg)

Do you have any ideas on how to proceed?

My site_id is a Foreign key of a Site table in table auth_user of Django

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was able to do:

views.py

```
def is_siteone(user):
    return user.site_id == 1 if user.site_id else False
```

template (main_list.html)

```
<h1>{{ user.site_id }}</h1>
    <p>---</p>
    <h1>{{ is_siteone }}</h1>

{#    {% for user in request.user.site.id %}#}
    {% if is_siteone %}
```

my balise {{ user.site_id }} return *siteone* in text and my balise {{ is_siteone }} return False

so I modified my code in views.py like this:

```
def is_siteone(user):
    return user.site_id == "siteone" if user.site_id else False
```

I specify that my context is like this, so I don't add (request.user) in the template

```
"is_siteone": is_siteone(request.user),
```

Comment: Hi, It still doesn't work after my last answer, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to access the `site_id` attribute directly from the `user` object, but `site_id` is not a direct attribute of the `User` model. Instead, it is a foreign key that relates the `User` model with the `Site` model, so try to do something like:

```py
def is_siteone(user):
    return user.site_id == 1 if user.site_id else False
```

Then in the template, use the function like this:

```html
{% if is_siteone(request.user) %}
    <!-- some content -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, I also came to this conclusion after a little more research but it still doesn't work

I've been trying with str and int but nothing works, I thought it was the format that was the problem but apparently it comes from somewhere else